# Replace Text with a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to find the answer to this; when I google it, all I get are "replace button text".

I want to hover over some text, and have that text replaced with a button.  I've tried the fadeIn/fadeOut technique and the Show/Hide technique.  However, the button becomes visible, it is in a different space.

Here's my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hidedsl6').hide();
    $('#showdsl6').hover(function(){
        $('#hidedsl6').fadeIn();
        }, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#hidedsl6').fadeOut();
    });
    $('#showfttn10').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn15').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn25').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn50').hover(function(){
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="DSL6">
<h3 class="DSLLocation" id="showdsl6">DSL 6</h3>
<button class="btn btntruespeed" id="hidedsl6" type="button">Order Now!</button>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.DSLLocation {
  margin-top: 110px;
}
.DSL6 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

So if anyone can help me.  I don't care if it's with Jquery, or just simple HTML/CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you simply trying to make some text appear as a button on hover? if so this should work nicely for you:

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 200ms ease
}

div:hover {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div>Psuedo button</div>
```

Or if you want to hide the text and show the button on hover:

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

button {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover button {
  display: block;
}

.container:hover .text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  <button>Psuedo Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Kind of, I want to hide the h3 tag and show a button tag.

Comment: I AM SUCH AN IDIOT.  I didn't think of making a div tag for my DSLLocation class.  That makes it a WHOLE lot easier!  Thank-you.

Comment: I'll accept in 3 minutes when I can.  Once again, thank-you.

Comment: @ThomasHutton Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that since you are replacing one element with another they might move due to the different content. Or you can style both elements the same way so that the change is not abrupt.

You could use just CSS for this

```css
.DSL6 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.DSL6 h3, .DSL6 button{margin:110px 0 0;padding:0;}
.DSL6 h3{display:block;}
.DSL6 button{display:none;}

.DSL6:hover h3{display:none;}
.DSL6:hover button{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="DSL6">
    <h3 class="DSLLocation" id="showdsl6">DSL 6</h3>
    <button class="btn btntruespeed" id="hidedsl6" type="button">Order Now!</button>
</div>
```